# How to redirect to last action in sailsjs using req.session?

Tags: sails.js, express-session

I am creating a login application where I need to redirect back to previous url from where the login action was called. I need to know does sails provide a built-in method by using which I can redirect to previous action without creating my own helper function.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this line in your policy if the users fails authentication and requires a login

```
if(req.method.toLowerCase() === 'get') req.session.afterLoginGoTo = req.originalUrl;
```

The above line makes sure they are doing a GET request as anything else provides another layer of complexity.

Then after you log the person in you can check for that and re-route

```
if(req.session.afterLoginGoTo) return res.redirect(req.session.afterLoginGoTo);
else res.redirect('/defaultHomePage');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the origin request from req and then use res.redirect()